# ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebApp - use Azure HttpsOnly or use HTTPS Redirection Middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I am developing a ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebApp (not MVC) website for deployment on Azure. What advantages are there to using [HTTPS Redirection Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) over simply configuring the Azure WebApp resource to use HTTPS only?

```
 az webapp update --resource-group XXX --name YYY --set HttpsOnly=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no.
As per information in your link, that answers you question:

> Note
>
> Apps deployed in a reverse proxy configuration allow the proxy to handle connection security (HTTPS). If the proxy also handles HTTPS redirection, there's no need to use HTTPS Redirection Middleware. If the proxy server also handles writing HSTS headers (for example, native HSTS support in IIS 10.0 (1709) or later), HSTS Middleware isn't required by the app.

The only concern here is — will your application be always hosted on configured correctly Azure? If there is a chance that the app can migrate to different cloud or be instantiated on misconfigured host, then it's better to have the middleware enabled.
Also this affects testing. If it is done on dedicated machines and not in the cloud, then, depending on will it be beneficial to have automatic redirects enabled, it can has sense to have this middleware as well.